# How to create main menu in wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am kinda of newbie in wordpress and i stuck into how to change main menu href category.. I try to find header in ftp files but still cant understand how to do it.. I look all wordpress help but stil cant do it.. Can someoner please help me undestand where to find the html file or php and change the hrefs links?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont find in HTML files. Go to admin panel -> Appearance -> Menues.

Then your menu will be there. Click the item and edit URL. That's it !

Comment: tnx m8.. i couldnt think of it....